# Finding, from cocoa application, if a package installer (like DivXInstaller.pkg) is running

Tags: objective-c, macos, bash, cocoa, installation

I do not know if this is possible, so I hope that the question does not appear stupid: 
I can get in a cocoa application, or even using a bash script, the pid of a specific running Application. So I can take actions (such as alert and ask if you want to close it).
We can the same with a package (pkg), knowing its id (like "org.someIdentity.pkg") in some way?

EDIT
this is what i use in cocoa:

```
    - (void)unWantedApp:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSLog(@"userInfo == %@", userInfo);

    if ([NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.blabla"] || [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.blabla2"]) {
        [[NSAlert alertWithMessageText:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"blabla is running..", nil), [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey]]
                         defaultButton:nil alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Well, I hope you are not joking with more then one Tool at same time...", nil)] runModal];


    }
}
```

EDIT

what i used with bash:

```
isOpen=$(ps auxwww | grep '/Applications/blabla.app' | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l)
if [ -e  '/Applications/blabla.app' ]; then
    if [ $isOpen -ge 0 ]; then
    # do what you are intresting for... But a packages is not in Application folder and is opened by Installer.app :-(
    fi
fi
```

EDIT
also the bash script can be used in cocoa in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash \n\
if [ -e '/Applications/blabla.app' ];then\n\
#variable and other statement here(escape all special caracter and manually add the new line ->> \n)\n\
else\n\
exit 0\n\
fi"

int main()
{
    system(SCRIPT);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you mention bash scripting... so what is wrong with the `ps` command? hard to tell what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: A PID is associated with a running *process*, not an application package.

Comment: ...well, once something in that application package _runs_ it's a process. With a PID. How do you determine the list of Applications to begin with? I am assuming you are cherry picking some interesting Applications anyway, so finding a process name instead shouldn't be that hard. If applications run with an absolute path you can probably look for _org.someIdentify_ anyway.

Comment: Yes, is hard to find what I'm looking for, so I asked a question. The only thing I can find is "Installer", but not his children (if we may say so), but this is not enough. Thank you for comment.

Comment: org.someIdentity? Yea! Is what i can't find for a running packages. Yes my app is intresting.... and wants to be sure that other applications (or packages that do something similar or are conflictual) are not running.

Comment: [NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.someid"] is my friend in cocoa :)

Comment: Well I added some examples that I use, the only thing I can do is see if Installer is running, and feel that it is wise to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps a bit:

```
app=${1:-VirtualBox}   #tested on it

run_searched() {
    echo "The installer installing $1 as: $2"
}
run_other() {
    echo "The installer NOT installing $1. (but installing: $2)"
}
not_running() {
    echo "The installer is not running"
}

isasdir="$HOME/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.installer.savedState"
isasfile="$isasdir/windows.plist"
if [[ -d "$isasdir" && -f "$isasfile" ]]
then
    win=$(plutil -p "$isasfile" | grep '"NSTitle"' | sed 's:.*"NSTitle".*=>.*"\([^"]*\)":\1:')
    if [[ "$win" =~ $app ]]
    then
        run_searched "$app" "$win"
    else
        run_other "$app" "$win"
    fi
else
    not_running
fi
```

Comment: @user3123201 EDITED - check it. ;) (also, you could delete the above un-necessary comments)

Comment: Thank you, this work...and I can translate to obj-c code too! I need some refinement but is a perfect starting point :)

Comment: @user3123201 - only remember, this is probably not an supported (official) API - I only found it and tried... ;)

Comment: Ok, but so far have never seen anything to do this. this is the first time (or probably the first attemp?). Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment with some questions, but I will provide some kind of answer too.

As mentioned in my comment: If the applications run with absolute path you can probably look for processes with *org.someIdentity*

If applications you want to 'monitor' are running from the same path(s), you could probably do something along these lines (bash):

```
apps="org.someIdentity org.someOtherIdentity"
for app in ${apps}; do
  echo "Checking app ${app}..."
  lsof /Applications/${app}
done
```

This is a crude example - you might have to expand on the paths a bit (I'm not on a Mac), but the idea is that the application/package names exist in the file structure (as directories). Running lsof on these directories will tell us which processes are using resources in that directory (i.e. opened files). Depending on your needs you can probably pass lsof some more parameters.
I'm not saying this is a very pretty approach, though ;)

Answer (score 0):

If using OS X 10.8 or later, [`pgrep`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/pgrep.1.html) is the best tool to return a list of process IDs by application name.

```
$ pgrep firefox
905
```

Comment: ..but is not installed on Mac OSX (I have the command line tool also)

Comment: @user3123201 `pgrep` is installed for me on OS X.  The binary should be located at `/usr/bin/pgrep`.

Comment: What OSX version? see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225/pgrep-and-pkill-alternatives-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @user3123201 I see.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, I'm on 10.7.5 on a MacPro. I've 10.9 also on my MacBookPro10,1 in assistance. This, however, do pgrep a command that can not be used, my app must work in 10.6 also. thank you anyway